# How to fix login keychain ruined after upgrade to macOS Sierra

Tags: keychain, login, macos

update on Oct 19:

I am still suffering from this. I tried a lot of ways. For instance, I removed the login KeyChain and created a new one. But it can't hold new items inside except I secured WiFi network. All the rest passwords can't be saved here.

[image: all the rest content can't be saved here]

I recently updated to the latest macOS Sierra. Though I am not completely sure whether this is the cause, my "login keychain" was totally ruined since then.

Every time I restart my Mac, I got a popup alert like this:

[image: The system was unable to unlock your login keychan]
(Please ignore the scar on my screen)

And when I opened the KeyChain App, I got this:

[image: readonly]

It says it's "Read Only".

Now I have to re-enter every password again (like check my email, log in my StackOverflow account, log in my facebook/twitter). And this happens every time I restart my Mac. It's so annoying. What should I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you get an answer, same thing here. I created a new keychain to get rid of the error, but I had hundreds of seldom used sites stored in there that I no clue what the passwords are anymore.

Comment: Try creating a new user account on the same mac and see if it happens there too.

Comment: Issues such as this are common if you 'upgrade' the OS over a well used older operating system. You effectively end up with a hybrid and a preference folder full of garbage. Always back-off your Mac to a remote drive (twice), wipe the primary drive clean (or better install a new one) and install your new OS clean. The re-install your software and import your data back onto the Mac. Takes longer but works every time.

Comment: I have huge files on my mac and if I backup every time it's like a nightmare. I'd rather stay at the old ways :(

Comment: Did you try this: open your keychain, click on the lock symbol to unlock (enter password), then quit keychain *leaving the lock open*.

Comment: @not2savvy tried but not working. i finally bought a new macbook.